# Replace single value in map

Tags: terraform

I have map like this and need to assign resource_id_tomonitor in my locals. because map is in my tfvars file vs locals is in my main.tf file

```
alerts_settings = {
    alert1 = {
    alert_name = "My First Alert"
    resource_group_name  = "my-rg"
    alert_criteria_settings = [
        {
        metric_namespace = "Microsoft.Network/networkWatchers/connectionMonitors"
        metric_name = "ChecksFailedPercent"
        metric_aggregation = "Average"
        metric_operator = "GreaterThanOrEqual"
        metric_threshold = "50.0"
        }
    ]
    resource_id_tomonitor = [] # to be replaced at runtime
    alert_description   = "from POC One fo the VM is Down but THis is not high priotiry as we have multiple VM serving Traffic"
    action_group_name     =   "POC-Monitor-AG"
    severity = 3
    },
        alert2 = {
    alert_name = "My Second Alert"
    resource_group_name  = "my-rg"
    alert_criteria_settings = [
        {
        metric_namespace = "Microsoft.Network/networkWatchers/connectionMonitors"
        metric_name = "ChecksFailedPercent"
        metric_aggregation = "Average"
        metric_operator = "GreaterThanOrEqual"
        metric_threshold = "100.0"
        }
    ]
    resource_id_tomonitor = [] # to be replaced at runtime
    alert_description   = "BOTH POC VM are Down. THis is HIGH priotiry P1 Issue"
    action_group_name     =   "POC-Monitor-AG"
    severity = 0
    },
}
```

how can i do something like

```
locals {
    var.alerts_settings["alert1"].resource_id_tomonitor="hello world"
    var.alerts_settings["alert2"].resource_id_tomonitor="hello world2"
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with a [for expression](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/for) and the [lookup function](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/lookup)

```
locals {
  alerts_settings = {
    alert1 = {
      alert_name            = "VM1 Down"
      resource_id_tomonitor = ""
    }
    alert2 = {
      alert_name            = "VM2 Down"
      resource_id_tomonitor = ""
    }
  }

  new_values = {
    alert1 = "hello world"
    alert2 = "hello world 2"
  }
}

output "updated" {
  value = { for k, a in local.alerts_settings : k => {
    alert_name            = a.alert_name
    resource_id_tomonitor = lookup(local.new_values, k, a.resource_id_tomonitor)
  } }
}
```

Which gives:

```
Changes to Outputs:
  + updated = {
      + alert1 = {
          + alert_name            = "VM1 Down"
          + resource_id_tomonitor = "hello world"
        }
      + alert2 = {
          + alert_name            = "VM2 Down"
          + resource_id_tomonitor = "hello world 2"
        }
    }
```

---

##### Update

In order to replace only a subset of keys, you can [merge](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/merge) the original map with a map containing the updates.

```
output "updated" {
  value = { for k, a in local.alerts_settings : k => merge(a, {
    resource_id_tomonitor = lookup(local.new_values, k, a.resource_id_tomonitor)
  }) }
}
```

Comment: Hi
this is working but can i go in loop dynamically instead of actually putting names for each element in alerts settings ? i have lot of elements in my map and i don't want to write all of them . i only want to give one i want to change rest remains same

Comment: Not sure I follow. Everything in `locals` in the example is just sample data. But for every element in alert settings, you have to tell terraform how you want to alter it. I'm not sure, without expanded sample data, precisely what you're looking for. There are no loops in terraform, aside from for expressions... sort of. You might consider checking out the CDK if you need some more complex control structure.

Comment: i have expanded the sample data. now if you can advise @theherk

Comment: Oh, I see. If I understand your question now correctly, the answer is, "Yeah, easily." You just use a simple merge. See updated answer.

Comment: yes this worked as expected. thanks @theherk

Comment: Nice hint with the merge. It works for me too.